# Where can I find the English version of "Music Box of Memories" series?

Tags: sono-hanabira

There is a series of *Sono Hanabira* Doujinshi called *Music Box of Memories* which I learned about from [Petals Garden](http://petalsgarden.axypb.net/xenocross-2/). However, when I try and use any of the links I get "Server not found".

My friend has tried contacting the site admin of Eden of Xeno (who made and sold *Music Box of Memories*) directly with email but got no reply, so I am wondering if there are any other places where I could get *Music Box of Memories*? I am only interested in the English version.

Also since they were released in an online yuri magazine called *Xenocross*, I wouldn't mind being able to get that but I am mainly interested in *Music Box of Memories*.

Comment: For those looking, take note that the doujin title is a R18+ eromanga.

Comment: I did find a link that was on dynasty-scans that had ch01. That was about it though.

Comment: @アズーサ i did a search there, your right it lists the first 2 chapters but chapter 3 is missing, she's still yet to get an email back so i suppose that's the best i can do if i wanted to read them, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only site I found that provides the English version of *Music Box of Memories* series is **Fakku! (Warning: R-18 site!)**.

Either you can:

- subscribe to Fakku! [to read each volume](https://www.fakku.net/collections/music-box-of-memories)

  > Based on the long-running yuri franchise *A Kiss For The Petals* by Fuguriya, *Music Box of Memories* contains three stories centered on three different character pairs. If you want to learn more about the franchise, check out Petals' Garden!
- purchase the digital version on [Fakku! Store](https://store.fakku.net/products/music-box-of-memories)

  > Based on the long-running yuri franchise *A Kiss For The Petals* by Fuguriya, *Music Box of Memories* contains three stories centered on three different character pairs. If you want to learn more about the franchise, check out [Petals' Garden](https://petalsgarden.axypb.net/)!
  >
  > This includes all 3 chapters of *Music Box of Memories*.

<sup>Disclaimer: I don't have any affiliation with the site at all.</sup>

Comment: I assume the links have all 3 volumes of it?

Comment: @Memor-X the store mentions "3 chapters" though. It seems the project was discontinued and it produced "3 volumes". I assume "chapter" means "volume" here, but I'm not sure.